# Use of "Could you tell what kind of"

Tags: syntactic-analysis, questions

What is the correct use of the verb in the following sentences:

1. Could you tell me what kind of qualifications does a deputy coroner **have**?
2. Could you tell me what kind of car he **owns**?
3. What kind of underwear does he **wear**?

In the first and second example, I think the question is `Could you`, so the rest of the sentence should be written in simple form. The second example follows this "rule", however, the first insists on adding another interrogative form in `does a deputy coroner have`.

In the third example I think that `What kind` is the question, but there is an additional interrogative form at the end.

Which one is correct?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Examples 2 and 3 are correct as they stand. Example 1 is only correct in Indian English, in which subordinate clauses in questions do not change their word order. Correct forms of example 1 in standard English include:

- Could you tell me what kind of qualifications a deputy coroner has?
- Could you tell me—what kind of qualifications does a deputy coroner have?
- What kind of qualifications does a deputy coroner have? Could you tell me?

Here, “what kind of qualifications a deputy coroner has” is simply a *noun phrase*, which can be used just about anywhere a noun can be used. A simpler example:

- How old are you?
- Do I know how old you are?
- I don’t know how old you are.

Notice that the interrogative is always inverted—*could you*, *does he*, *are you*, and so on.

Comment: Great. An additional question: Why _What kind of qualifications_  is not considered an interrogative sentence on its own with the last part _a deputy coroner has_ as a subordinate clause?

Comment: I'm thinking that maybe it is because a deputy coroner has is not a full sentence. Could you clarify this?